# Disable/Remove app menu from gnome shell 3.10

Tags: 14.04, gnome, gnome-shell-extension

I seriously loathe the app menu that gnome-shell shows.

There used to be an extension https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/32/remove-panel-app-menu/ but it does not work in gnome-shell 3.10

There is a setting in the gnome-tweak-tool to not show the app menu , but that also does not work

I have been searching the internet like a mad dog but no specific solutions to gnome-shell 3.10

anyone achieved this yet ?

I am sure there should be some setting that could be changed using the dconf-editor.

Comment: Did you try changing the supported versions in metadata.json?

Comment: 'That also does not work'. Try enabling the option in Gnome Tweak Tool, the restarting the shell ('Alt'+'F2', enter `r` and press enter)  and see if it works (disable the extension and restart the shell FIRST if the extension is enabled).

Comment: Gnome tweak tool did not work for me as i have mentioned in the question itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This gnome extension can do that: [taskbar](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/584/taskbar/)

The option to hide the app menu is under the Misc tab.

Comment: thanks @Luca ...somehow i had missed seeing this option. awesome..